# Ruby on Rails - Stripe - No API key provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm trying out this Stripe quick checkout for my webshop, form appears fine but when redirected and run the **charges#create** I get an error saying **No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = ".** as far as I've learned I have set it up in the **stripe.rb**

```
  Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => Rails.application.secrets.stripe_publishable_key,
    :secret_key      => Rails.application.secrets.stripe_secret_key
  }

  Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.stripe_secret_key
```

The error comes in **charges_controller.rb**

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  require 'stripe'

  def index
    render :new
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 500

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

end
```

Here is also how I setup my **secrets.yml**

```
 shared:
   stripe_api_key: sk_test_####################
   stripe_publishable_key: pk_test_###############
   secret_key_base: ##############################
```

Here is a gif showing what happens when I click pay in the stripe payment session: [imgur gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnUjx.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to the following in `stripe.rb`

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => ENV['stripe_publishable_key'],
    :secret_key => ENV['stripe_api_key']
}
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

**Additional Which I Have Used**

Look you need to set stripe [`STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY` & `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails#testing-the-integration) for setting these keys securely you can use [`figaro gem`](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) after installing Figaro gem then a file will create inside `config` directory which name `application.yml` you can set your keys like this

```
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY: pk_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: sk_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Then update your `stripe.rb` inside `config/initializers/`

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
    :secret_key => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
}
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

That's it, you have done this.

Comment: So now instead I get this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/0VR21)

Dont know if I understood you right but here is what I changed 
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => ENV['pk_test_RFAInQ536Y3Iy8KhryKoIThc'],
    :secret_key => ENV['sk_test_AKgW9WEjOcWlfBb2PAP98Gr8']
}
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]

Comment: Ohh! look if you use directly keys which you have tried then it will look like this `publishable_key => 'pk_test_RFAInQ536Y3Iy8KhryKoIThc'` and the secret key is the same & you don't need `ENV[]`, it will work but that's not secured

Comment: Yeah but I'm still getting the same error as before

Comment: I mean the original problem with an error occuring when trying to retrieve **Stripe.api_key** in the **charges#create** getting the error **No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = ".**

Comment: Tested the other one you suggested with Figaro and it works just like I wanted it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put the API key in an initializer? Better yet, store it as an environment variable and reference that. Create `config/initializers/stripe.rb` with the following content

`Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET']
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = ENV['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY']`

Comment: the first codeblock above is from config/initializers/stripe.rb